# Can I ask this question: Is there any aspect of a nuclear weapon test that cannot be simulated using super computers?

Tags: discussion

Nuclear weapons tests are experiments carried out to determine the effectiveness, yield, and explosive capability of nuclear weapons. However, these days most nuclear weapon states uses Super computers to simulate nuclear weapon testing.

Therefore, can all the parameters of a nuclear test be determined using computer simulation only?

Answer (score 2):

The concerns I have about the question are mostly meta concerns.

Nominally, yes, the question should be on-topic as phrased.

---

One of my concerns is that the question is flirting with being a poll.  If we rephrase the question as "What aspects of nuclear weapons can't be simulated", then it's very clearly a poll.  Polls don't work so well in the StackExchage Q&A format for a number of reasons.

Another part of my concern is that I would expect to see some backing evidence or research regarding some of the claims.  For example, when you state "most nuclear weapon states uses super computers to simulate nuclear weapon testing", what evidence are you backing that claim with.

It's good to keep the question scoped to a specific area as you mentioned.  It wouldn't hurt to define effectiveness for this particular scenario.  Are you referring to volume of the warhead to explosive damage / range?  Or is it some other comparison such as cost?<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> <sub>*I wouldn't expect nuclear warheads to be subject to all that many project management cost controls, but I could very well be wrong.*</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes, I was referring to volume of the warhead, explosive range, radioactive fallout and not the cost.  If time permits can you please suggest a better way to phrase this question so that it doesn't sound like a poll . And yes, I can provide evidence to support the claim

Comment: @D_S - Phrasing it as you did "Is there an(y) aspect ... that can't be simulated ..." should be fine.

Comment: ...and you should definitely put a limit on the scope. Simulating parameters of the explosion (energy spectrum) - yes. Simulating effects of the explosion? Biological, chemical... political? Sociological? These things elude computer simulations.

Comment: i thought it almost sounds like an open ended question.